# Spy on a function inside functional component using React testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to spy on a function inside a function component using react testing library. I wanted to test whether `handleClick` function has been called whenever the button is clicked.

Here's excerpt from my code

**Component**

```
const Foo = () => {
  
  const handleClick = () => {}

  return <div>
     <button data-testid="button" onClick={handleClick}>Continue</button>
  </div>
}
```

**Test case**

```
  it("should handle continue button click", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Foo />);
    const button = getByTestId("button");
    const spy = jest.spyOn(Foo, "handleClick");
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.click(button);
    });
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The error I'm getting is as below

```
Cannot spy the handleClick property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Testing internal implementation details isn't what React Testing Library is about. Test using the component's API, i.e. it's props and it's UI. Your component also appears to be missing the `"button"` test id so the query will fail to target the button element. Since the component isn't a class there's no instance to get a method/property reference of.

Comment: A function defined inside a function is **not** magically a property of the outer function. Don't test implementation; test the _behaviour_ handleClick provides.

Comment: I forgot to mention it here. But, I added the `data-testid` @DrewReese

Comment: @jonrsharpe makes sense, so i do not have to spy on anything if I'm using react testing library. I will just need to test what result is expected when user performs an action on UI.

Comment: You might have to spy on things, but test doubles are for _collaborators_ not the thing you're supposed to be testing.

Comment: I do not agree that whether the handler is called is an implementation detail. Along with the UI rendered by component, the calls for a handler is component's "side effects", the stuff that is expected to be produced by component for the outside world. It should be unit-tested.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to spy on `handleClick`. Instead, you want to test what effect `handleClick` had on the component. Your `handleClick` callback is an implementation detail, and as a general rule, you don't test that.

Comment: What about testing a disabled component? It would make sense to check if it didn't invoke the "handleClick" function no?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to spy on handleClick as if it was a property of Foo, which is a function.

I can move handleClick to another file and import it both in the component and the test:

handler.js

```
export const handleClick = () => {}
```

Component

```
import { handleClick } from './handler.js'
const Foo = () => {

return <div>
   <button data-testid="button" onClick={handleClick}>Continue</button>
</div>
}
```

Test case

```
import * as handlers from './handler.js';

it("should handle continue button click", async () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Foo />);
  const button = getByTestId("button");
  const spy = jest.spyOn(handlers, "handleClick");
  act(() => {
    fireEvent.click(button);
  });
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```